# Help for finding Bases of Sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling on a linear algebra assignment where I have to find the basis of the set: $U=\{\left[\begin{array}{c}a \\b \\ c\end{array}\right]|\ a,b,c\in \mathbb R, a=2b+3c\}\subseteq\mathbb R^{3}$. I don't really understand how to do this when I look at other examples. The question first required me to prove that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^{3}$ (I used the subspace test). Now for this basis portion, I know that I need to use a system of equations to find a spanning set and show its linear independence. I got stuck after thinking of how to form a system using only the given information of $a-2b-3c=0$. How would I use linear combinations to find the basis of $U$? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! (I'm a first year engineering student who is new to vector (sub)spaces, just to give context on my current knowledge).

Comment: Alternatively, find a nonzero vector in $U$. Then find another one, but not a scalar multiple of the first one. Then argue from geometry that those two vectors form a basis for $U$.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many choices for a basis for $U$, but one choice becomes fairly obvious if you think of a typical member of $U$ as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix}2b+3c\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2b\\b\\0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}3c\\0\\c\end{pmatrix} = b\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I see, so I just had to show that a is linearly dependent of b and c and form a linear combination to form the matrix. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you already know $a$ is linearly dependent on $b$ and $c$ because you are told that $a=2b+3c$. And now you also know that any vector in U is a linear combination of the two vectors $(2,1,0)^T$ and $(3,0,1)^T$.